# SQL Insert data from table to another along with user input

Tags: sql-server, select, insert

```
[Table1 Columns: Server, Site, App_Name]
[Table2 Columns: Event, Server, Site, App_Name]


INSERT INTO Table2 Values(Server, Site, App_Name)
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Site IN ('ABC');
UPDATE Table2 SET Event = 'XYZ' WHERE Site IS NOT NULL;
```

I want to set the same Event value for all rows created in query1. If I do update, it corrupts some previous data. How do I make the second query as part of the INSERT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
    INSERT INTO Table2 Values(Server, Site, App_Name)
SELECT Server,'XYZ',App_Name FROM Table2 WHERE Site IN ('ABC');
```